# Print unmarshalled MIME request parts using Camel routes (XML)

Tags: apache-camel, mime, unmarshalling, spring-camel, camel-http

I am working with Camel Routes (XML) to process a MIME request that contains attachments. I have successfully unmarshalled the request using . However, when I log the body of the unmarshalled request, it only shows the content of the first attachment.

I would like to know how I can refer to all the parts (attachments) of the unmarshalled request. Specifically, I need to access the content of each attachment individually.

Is there a way to iterate over the attachments or retrieve them by some other means in Camel Routes (XML)? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

My camel route

```
<routes xmlns = "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id = "direct:uploadDocument" streamCache = "true">
        <from uri = "direct:uploadDocument"/>
        <bean ref = "logger" method = "info(request = ${body})"/>
        <unmarshal><mimeMultipart/></unmarshal>
        <bean ref ="logger" method = "info('Unmarshal successful')"/>
        <bean ref = "logger" method = "info(Unmarshalled request = ${body})"/>
    </route>
</routes>
```